# Why can the documents referred to by a PHP MongoCursor object changes after a for each loop iterates through it?

Tags: php, mongodb, cursor

First I will explain the situation, then I will ask the question.

**SITUATION:**

Assuming a PHP MongoDB database object "db" that refers to a database that has a collection called "products". Each document in our "products" collection looks like this:

```
{ 
  _id: <ObjectId>
  upc_code: <int>
  discontinued: <BOOL>
  for_sale: <BOOL>
  modified: <Date>
}
```

Imagine there are thousands of these documents. Also imagine that for each, "discontinued" is false, and "for_sale" is true. The modified dates are not all the same.

Step 1: we search for the 100 oldest-modified products:

```
$newProducts = db->products->find(array('discontinued'=>false))->sort(array('modified'=>1))->limit(100);
```

Step 2: we do a "for each" loop through the $newProducts, and check each one's "upc_code" via an API to an external web service. For each product that has been discontinued, update the database, setting its "discontinued" value to **true**:

```
foreach($newProducts as $product) {
    $discontinued = checkAPI($product['upc_code']);
    if($discontinued) {
        $update = array('$set'=>array('discontinued'=>true));
        db->products->update->(array('_id'=>$product['_id']),$update);
    }
}
```

Step 3: after that is done, we again iterate through $newProducts with a "for each" loop and make an array of the "_id" values:

```
$mongo_ids = array();
foreach($newProducts as $product) {
    $mongo_ids[] = $product['_id'];
}
```

Step 4: we update all products whose "_id" values are $in that array, to $set their "modified" value to the current time:

```
$modified = myFunctionToGetCurrentTime();
$query = array('_id'=>array('$in'=>$mongo_ids));
$update2 = array('$set'=>array('modified'=>$modified)); 
$options = array('upsert'=>false,'multiple'=>true);
db->products->update($query,$update2,$options);
```

The problem is that none of the products whose "discontinued" value got set to **true** will have its "modified" property updated in Step 4 because $products is a MongoCursor object, and therefore in Step 3 $products refers to a different set of documents than it does in Step 2, due to the fact that in Step 2, in some of the documents we update the value of the same property that the MongoCursor's query is based on ("discontinued").

**QUESTION:**

Therefore my question is, firstly, why does the set of documents referred to by the MongoCursor object change like this? Is there a way to "bake" it, so that the documents it found at the time of the query don't change later? If there is no way to "bake" it (so to speak), then what would be the best way to store the returned documents in a variable that will not be dynamic?

(Note: I know that I can do something like **$newProductsArray = iterator_to_array($newProducts)** after Step 1 to store the results of the query in a static variable. I'm more just curious about if there might be a way to set the MongoCursor's options so that wouldn't be necessary.)

Comment: @jdo Good point. I also thought of that, and yes, it would seem to work fine. I find it weird that, on the one hand, the set of documents to which the MongoCursor refers does not change while we are inside the foreach loop, even though in that loop we are updating the "discontinued" property of some of the documents as we go -- but on the other hand, as in the original post's situation, *after* the foreach loop the set of documents referred to by the MongoCursor is suddenly different. Why does it happen that way? Is there a way to make it not do that?

Comment: @jdo seemed to delete his comment just before I posted my reply to it. He had asked why not just merge Step 3 into Step 2?